# Bitbucket is not cloning all folders

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone

Yesterday I pushed all my project files to a repo called **my repo**

Today, when I clone the repo on another computer it clones all files **except one folder** which name is something like **event-calendar[2340sdfda0s]**

Can you tell me how can I get all folders when I clone a repo?

Here is the repo screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot it looks like Bitbucket sees that folder as a submodule. It could be due to wrong configuration in the Git repository or something else (from just a screenshot is really hard to tell). So you have two options here:

- Reinitialize the repository and make sure that folder is not added as submodule
- Clone the repo with  `git clone --recurse-submodules my/repo/origin`

But I prefer the first solution since chances are this behavior is not intended

Comment: you mean, I need to clone the repo with : git clone --resource-submodules git@bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx.git

Comment: No, the general command is exactly what I wrote in the answer, you just need to replace `my/repo/origin` with your actual git repository URL. But if you have a submodule in your repository but no `.gitmodules` file, then you really should check out what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

This folder is a submodule.

You should see a `.gitmodules` file under your root.
You can delete the current folder and clone it again or use the commands below to update your submodule:

#### Cloning a repository with submodules

If you want to clone a repository including its submodules you can use the `--recursive` parameter.

```
# Cloning a repository with submodules
git clone --recursive <url>
```

#### Update submodules after clone

```
git submodule init
git submodule update

# Or
git submodule update --init submoduleName
```

#### Fetch and checkout any nested submodules

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

#### To view submodule status

```
git submodule status
```

---

As you can see in the image below, a submodule is simply a sub-project inside your project.

[image]

Comment: there is no .gitmodules file in my local project directory :(